# check duplicate values with messy data and conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a row with phone numbers and I want to highlight duplicates using conditional formatting. Problem is the numbers are often entered sloppily, sometimes there are whitespaces and sometimes a number starts with 0.

For example, the data could look like this:

```
123 456 78
0 123 45678
12345678
54312344
0543 12344
```

(the first 3 numbers and the last 2 should be highlighted as duplicates)

The formula I have written so far is this:

```
=COUNTIF(D:D,IF(LEFT(D1) = "0",SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(D1,LEN(D1) - 1)," ",""), SUBSTITUTE(D1, " ", ""))) > 1
```

But that one does not work and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula on your conditional formatting:

```
=COUNTIF(D:D,REGEXREPLACE(D:D,"\s+|(0)+",""))
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]